# Sending mail in Nuxt.js with nuxt-mail

Tags: javascript, vue.js, email, axios, nuxt.js

I am a total newbie at Nuxt.js/Vue.js so here are some newbie questions :D

I am having problems with sending mail from a contact from in my Nuxt.js application. I am trying to use nuxt-mailer but I can't make it work.  I have installed `axios` and [nuxt-mail](https://github.com/dword-design/nuxt-mail).

I get 500 (Internal Server Error).

So I  am adding this in `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
'@nuxtjs/axios',
['nuxt-mail', {
  message: {
    to: 'my-email',
  },
  smtp: {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 587,
  },
}],
```

Am I supposed to put the mail where I want to receive the mail in the 'to'?
And am should I pit just `localhost` in `host` or `http://localhost`?
And lastly what should I pun for 'port'? Is that 3000 as the post on my localhost?

Okay next, my form in the component likes like this:

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <form>    
      <label for="name">Ditt namn</label>            
      <input id="name" type="text" v-model="name"/>

      <label for="email">Din epostadress</label>            
      <input id="email" type="email" v-model="email"/>

      <label for="phone">Telefon</label>            
      <input id="phone" type="phone" v-model="phone"/>

      <label for="message"> Meddelande: </label>
      <textarea id="message" v-model="message"/>
      
      <button type="submit" @click.prevent="send">Send email </button>
    </form>
   </div>
</template>
```

and the script lokes like this:

```js
<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    phone: '',
    message: '',
  }),
  methods: {
    send() {
        this.$mail.send({
        name: this.name,
        from: this.email,
        phone: this.phone,
        subject: 'Message from contact-form',
        text: this.message,
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

So what can be the problem? A wonder if I am doing something wrong in the nuxt.config.js file? But i don't know at all.

Hope someone can help :)

Comment: Are you planning to use this in a static site or a node-hosted one ? I'm asking because it will not work on a full static one and because in that case, you may look for a totally different service IMO.

Comment: No, not on a static site. It will be on a node-hostet one.

Comment: Alright, so my answer is still valid.

Comment: Yes thank you for helping! I think it is the problem you described with that it will not work on localhost. i am all new to this so that dit not even cross my mind, so thanks for pointing that out to me! i will look in ti the mail sending services you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the readme and the related page of [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/), it looks like that:

- `to` refers to the actual email address of the receiver, something like `kuro@yourdomain.com`
- host needs to be a valid hosted SMTP server, so localhost is probably no the good one here, since it will 100% not work once pushed to production
- the port depends of the SMTP configuration essentially: `defaults to 587 if is secure is false or 465 if true` (from `nodemailer` documentation)

Here is a blog article to setup some emails **IF** you will be using the node part of your Nuxt app: https://blog.lichter.io/posts/emails-through-nuxtjs/

Here is a blogpost on how to especially use `nuxt-mail`: https://dword-design.de/blog/sending-emails-with-nuxt-js-the-easy-way/

You will still need a mail sending service to have this work, on Mailtrap thanks to Mailgun, Sendgrid, Mailchimp or alike.

---

You can also use Netlify functions for that: https://css-tricks.com/netlify-functions-for-sending-emails/ or any other [serverless functions](https://github.com/anaibol/awesome-serverless#email-sending-subscriptions-and-newsletters)

As you can see, the configuration is not trivial and there are several ways to achieve this but it essentially comes down of using an exernal service, especially if you plan on going full-static only.

Comment: I tried with Mailtrap just now and it worked all fine! Thanks for all the help. :)

Answer (score 5):

I accidentally happen to be the developer of nuxt-mail :). Just found this post while working on the module.

So, kissu already mentioned most relevant things. You need a running mail server, localhost won't work here (and will likely be the source issue). What you can do is have a look at [Mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io/). It basically does what you are looking for, meaning it provides a mail server for testing and local development. Emails will land in a special inbox that you can inspect and empty at your behalf. You can even use an API to check the inbox.

Hope this helps, if you happen to be using nuxt-mail, feel free to [file an issue](https://github.com/dword-design/nuxt-mail/issues) if there's anything, or write me on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/seblandwehr).

Comment: Yes i tried with Mailtrap just now and it worked all fine! Thanks for answering and a greate module. :)