# Nuxtjs - Error 404 with post request in production while working in local

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

I'm actually trying to use [nuxt-mail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-mail) in a personnal project,

During my development phase, I receive all my testing mails. And from there I did the following adjustments to do the exact same request from my builded site :

```
//nuxt.config.js
env: {
  baseUrl:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev'
      ? 'http://localhost:3000'
      : 'https://my-domain.netlify.app'
},
```

My code when using the *'send'* function :

```
this.$axios.$post(process.env.baseUrl + "/mail/send", {
        config: 'contact',
        from: document.getElementById('input-2').value,
        subject: document.getElementById('subject').value,
        text: "This is a text message",
      })
```

It continues to work well with *localhost/3000/mail/send* but I have a 404 error once I build my site and using *https:/ /my-domain.netlify.app/mail/send* :

```
POST https://my-domain.netlify.app/mail/send                             [HTTP/2 404 Not Found 186ms]
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
```

I'm actually struggling to solve this problem, am I missing something ?

Comment: have you test the `https://my-domain.netlify.app/mail/send` by postman? whether the api works well?

Comment: What is your `target` value and where is your code hosted?

Comment: @User10519069 I just tryed to do this via Postman and it's giving me the same 404 Error. I still don't understand how it can work in local and not in production.

Comment: @kissu my target is defined in the Nuxt modules :  `modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    ['nuxt-mail', {
      message: [
        {
        name: 'contact',
        to: 'my-email-target...",
        }
      ],
      smtp: {
        //Config of my sending mail
        },
      },
    }],`

Comment: No, the `target` of your Nuxt project. https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-target

Comment: @kissu I did not fill it in, so it is by default assigned to "server"

Comment: So, you do `yarn build` and host it on Netlify? Do you use any serverless functions?

Comment: @kissu Yes it's automatically built and hosted on Netlify and I don't need to build it with server target, I switched it to `static` but still have this 404 error with my production URL 

Comment: @kissu Hi, I just tested it now, thanks for helping, you were right, the problem were that I was using `static` target, using Heroku I managed to deploy my project using the send email function !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so if your `target` is `static`, you can **only** do `yarn generate`.
If you do have the default, aka `target: server`, you can **only** `yarn build`.

Then, as talked about it a bit here: [Sending mail in Nuxt.js with nuxt-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67107988/8816585)
You cannot use a Node.js package in a static environment, so neither `yarn generate` nor Netlify will help you here. You need to `yarn build` and host it on something like [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/).

One last step that you can do, is to try it locally with the following:

- `target: server`
- `yarn build`
- `yarn start`
- make your POST call with Postman or alike

If it does not work here, it is a code issue and you can look into the hosting one.
If it does work locally, you can proceed to the hosting issue that you'll face.

Answer (score 0):

Well you just misunderstood the env field in the nuxt.config.js file.
That env field is passed to the $config Object of the Nuxt App and not passed to process.env.

What you want is to set the BaseUrl for the Axios Module

```js
// nuxt.config.js
axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev'
      ? 'http://localhost:3000'
      : 'https://my-domain.netlify.app'
  },

// or provide a runtime config
// server and clientside
publicRuntimeConfig: {
    axios: {
      browserBaseURL: process.env.BROWSER_BASE_URL
    }
  },

// serverside only
  privateRuntimeConfig: {
    axios: {
      baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL
    }
  },
```

Edit:
Also when calling axios just do it like that if you implement the above changes

```js
this.$axios.$post("/mail/send", {
// ... the rest of your code
```

Comment: I deleted my env field because you're right, I want to use Axios module. I first tryed to add the configuration to my Axios Module, it works well in localhost, but not in production, just getting the same 404 error. Then I tryed to use the runtime config instead of axios config, this time I got a Cross Origin Request because It tryed to consult *http://localhost:3000/mail/send* instead of *https://my-domain.netlify.app/mail/send*.