# How to setup Contact Email for Static Generated site in Nuxt

Tags: node.js, vue.js, web-applications, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I have a Site which is built on Nuxt and deployed on Netlify. I have used 'static' method in nuxt.config.js and Generated the dist Folder.

I want to send an email from my contact page whenever user fills the contact form. It seems to work fine in my local server but on Netfliy domain it is failing and still points to http:localhost/3000. I am using the package  [Nuxt-Mail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-mail) to send emails Unfortuneately the package only works for "Server" type websites.

Can anyone help me to setup email in the "static" generated website.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nuxtjs - Error 404 with post request in production while working in local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68421603/nuxtjs-error-404-with-post-request-in-production-while-working-in-local)

Comment: Two of my answers (you can get the second through my comment above) are answering this in depth. Please make a search before posting next time.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure of the exact thing that you need here but Formspree may be enough maybe? Or even Netlify forms (contact form, not sending emails).

Comment: @kissu have gone through the linked article it says I can only configure it if I am using the "server" in nuxt config and deploy it in heroku well I am trying to deploy it in netlify. 
there is no way i can achieve this with "static" and deploy it in netlify?

Comment: No, you need a Node.js server. Netlify is not providing you one and Nuxt2 is not able to do it on an Edge function or something other serverless architecture.

Comment: @kissu The issue is resolved Formspree gives the option to send the email on a static Server Thanks a ton!!

Comment: Yeah, Formspree can be used to send some info without requiring a backend (Node server). Netlify forms do that also. Meanwhile, it's not mails directly into Nuxt (quite different even).

Comment: @kissu Formspree does the Job. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I've been using formspree.io which is fairly straight forward. It might be useful to you. Just pings off an email whenever someone submits a form. You can try mailygo. It also handy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).