# How to send emails in nuxt and vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

My website has its server side on NuxtJs and the UI in VueJs, and I want to send mail from contact form in this website.
I tried a lot of different options but none of them are working.

I tried EmailJs in Vue but it is working on localhost but not on server.

I also tried nuxt-mail but that cannot work because it is a static website and uses `nuxt generate`.

At last I tried, node-mailer, but the problem with that is that node-mailer works on different port and my website is on different port and that's why I cant run and it also uses `HandlebarsJs` and therefore it clashes with VueJs.

If someone can please help me out with the same, ThankYou.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a Node server to serve your emails (hence why it's working locally, because of Webpack) or use a paid service to do it for you. Vue is a front-end framework, therefore it cannot send emails by itself.

Also, you should have 2 apps, your front-end and your backend. Don't try to mix them if you're aiming for a simple solution. (it's also more logical to just split them)

My previous answer may be helpful too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67109586/8816585